# Selecting library at runtime in C

Tags: c, exec, dynamic-linking

I am currently creating a parser library, and for testing purposes I would like to be able to load one of several parsers while a main repl is running.  It reads commands and executes parsers, which can be exited by hitting Ctrl-D, like the shell.  How should I select the parser I want at runtime?  Should I:

1. Include all of the parsers I might use and run the one the user selects,
2. Load and unload the required parsers using a dynamic library system like dlfcn (or a better alternative?),
3. Fork-exec a separate program for each parser, or
4. Not use a main repl and just compile a repl into each parser and run them all separately.

I want my program to be cross platform (so if I do 2 or 3 I'll need to use a sloppy function on windows) and preferably memory and cpu light.  T don't want to be given a full solution, just to know which of my ideas (or another) would work best.

Here is my main program (which does not currently switch parsers without being recompiled):

```
//run_parser.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "get_line.h"//getline clone
#include "ptree.h"//parse tree library; used for all parsers
#include "parser_llk.h"//parser library; used for all parsers
#include "tree_parser.h"//two different parsers that I do not want loaded at the same time, if feasible.
#include "calc_parser.h"
#include "debug.h"
#define START start //current compile-time parser switch
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *file = stdin;
    if(argc < 2){
        puts("No file specified, reading from stdin:");
    }else{
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(!file){
            printf("Could not open \"%s\"!  Reading from stdin:\n", argv[1]);
            file = stdin;
        }
    }
    size_t length = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    int read = 0;
    Position *p;
    Ptree *t;
    while((read = getLine(&line, &length, file)) > 0){
        line[read - 1] = '\0'; //remove new line
        printf("\"%s\"\n", line);
        t = mallocPtree();
        p = firstPosition(line);
        if(START(p, t)){//calls the START parser on the line entered (THE THING I WANT TO CHANGE AT RUNTIME)
            puts("Parsed successfully.  Output:");
            flattenTagged(t);//remove most single child nodes in parse trees (all but those with no grandchildren)
            printPtree(t, 0);
        }else{
            puts("Parsed unsuccessfully");
        }
        deletePtree(t);
        free(t);
        free(p);
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(file);
}
```

My current implementation just loads every parser by #including and linking it, which does not seem scaleable to more parsers with more complicated post processing (like interpreters).  Every parser is expected to have a `start` function that parses some input and an `execute` function that starts post processing (interpreting, compiling, calculating, etc).  If I go with strategy 1 or 4, this is really all I need.  If I use 2 or 3, I will actually be able to load the parsers one at a time like I want to.  Which of these approaches should I use?  Should I bother with only loading the parsers I use, or is it not worth it compared to loading them all?

Comment: What is a "sloppy function?"

Comment: Any windows api function :P

Comment: Does linking them as shared libraries not work for you?

Comment: Shared libraries would also work well, probably much better than dynamic loading.

Comment: If you want your *users* to extend your program (write their own parsers) you should take route 2 (in which case having a look at GNU Libtool might be worth it).  If you know the set of parsers at distribution time, just compile everything together.

Comment: Right now I would only be using the main program for testing and any final or user code would only be linked to the parser_llk and ptree libraries, not any other parsers or the main repl.  But I think It would be better to have it accessible for testing user functions.

Comment: I think that I'll use dynamic libraries because they are the only option that really gives me what I want: to add parsers without recompiling.  I could do that with fork-exec, but inter-process communication and multi-process debugging would then become an issue.  I am just a little wary because this is my first big project in programming and I have heard that dynamic libraries are difficult or dangerous to use.  Inexperience and danger are a great combination.  What exactly are the specific downsides to dynamic libraries?